# Jenkins publish HTML from docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I recently switched to using docker containers in my Jenkins pipelines and it seems that the jenkins HTML publisher plugin doesn't seem to work from within the container.

What I mean by that, is that after the build an HTML file is generated, which I wish to be published. I am using the HTML publisher plugin for that which worked perfectly fine until switching to building with containers.

Should the HTML publisher plugin work from within the container? If not are there any alternatives to publishing the HTML from within the container?

Thank you.

Comment: You might find something useful in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296102/jenkins-getting-test-results-from-docker-slave

Comment: I know this comment might be too late, but at the time of the question, the HTML publisher plugin did not work from the container (it was not container aware). You had to copy the HTML into the Jenkins build workspace and publish it from there.

Answer (score 1):

The publisher plugin will work inside of the container, but not if you are trying to access an area inside the container. This means if you need to access something like the /etc of the container, you will not be able to because the plugin will actually be accessing the /etc of the Jenkins host. You can the workspace though inside of the container though.